# Running out of RAM when adding large arrays to be manipulated in a function

Tags: c, arrays, ram

I'm having a problem with the RAM limitation of my microcontroller (max of 124KB). Here is the part of my code that is giving me some headache:

```
// Declaring arrays (they actually need to be float)
// The three dots (...) means that there are several more numbers inside the arrays (actually there are 345 numbers inside each array).
float AR_KELON_POWER_COOL_21_FANMAX[] = {1,348,174,21,66,21,66,...,3800};
float AR_KELON_SWING_COOL_21_FANMAX[] = {1,347,173,21,65,21,65,...3800};
float AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN1[] = {1,348,174,21,65,21,65,21,21,...,3800}
float AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN2[] = {1,348,173,21,66,21,66,21,...,3800}
float AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN3[] = {1,348,173,21,66,21,66,21,20,...,3800}
float AR_KELON_COOL_18_FANMAX[] = {1,348,173,21,66,21,66,21,...,3800}
float AR_KELON_COOL_19_FAN1[] = {1,348,174,21,66,21,66,21,21,...,3800}
//Will be adding more arrays

//array of pointers
float *airConditionerCommands[] = {
    AR_KELON_POWER_COOL_21_FANMAX,
    AR_KELON_SWING_COOL_21_FANMAX,
    AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN1,
    AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN2,
    AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN3,
    AR_KELON_COOL_18_FANMAX,
    AR_KELON_COOL_19_FAN1
// I put more arrays inside here as I declare the arrays
}


void executeCommands(int data) {
    int i=0;
    int command=0;

    for(i=0; airConditionerCommands[i] != NULL; i++) {
        command = i + 67;
        if(command == data) {
            //This function will execute some instructions as it reads the array airConditionerCommands[i].
            sendIR(airConditionerCommands[i], 400, 38); 
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

This program works perfectly if there are less than about 110 declared arrays (and abviously put inside of *airConditionerCommands[]). But if I declare more arrays the program won't be compiled, because there is no more RAM left in the microcontroller.
Is there a way around this? I don't have too much experience with C, but I think there is a way to allocate and free the memory the arrays are using.

Any help would be awsome. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using floats for what appear to be integers? That could save you some memory.

Comment: You are allocating all arrays on stack. Try allocating them on heap instead.

Comment: What microcontroller/compiler are you using?

Comment: STM32F207VCT6 and uVision from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On microcontrollers, immutable data -- i.e. data you will never even try to modify --, can be stored in the program flash/ROM instead of RAM. All you need is to declare both the array and its data elements as `const` or `static const`.

In other words, use

```
// Declaring arrays (they actually need to be float)
// The three dots (...) means that there are several more numbers inside the arrays (actually there are 345 numbers inside each array).
const float AR_KELON_POWER_COOL_21_FANMAX[] = {1,348,174,21,66,21,66,...,3800};
const float AR_KELON_SWING_COOL_21_FANMAX[] = {1,347,173,21,65,21,65,...3800};
const float AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN1[] = {1,348,174,21,65,21,65,21,21,...,3800}
const float AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN2[] = {1,348,173,21,66,21,66,21,...,3800}
const float AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN3[] = {1,348,173,21,66,21,66,21,20,...,3800}
const float AR_KELON_COOL_18_FANMAX[] = {1,348,173,21,66,21,66,21,...,3800}
const float AR_KELON_COOL_19_FAN1[] = {1,348,174,21,66,21,66,21,21,...,3800}
//Will be adding more arrays
```

If the command sequences themselves are immutable, then you can do

```
//array of pointers
const float *const airConditionerCommands[] = {
    AR_KELON_POWER_COOL_21_FANMAX,
    AR_KELON_SWING_COOL_21_FANMAX,
    AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN1,
    AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN2,
    AR_KELON_COOL_18_FAN3,
    AR_KELON_COOL_18_FANMAX,
    AR_KELON_COOL_19_FAN1,
    // I put more arrays inside here as I declare the arrays
    NULL
}
```

too. If checked it right, the STM32F207VCT6 only has 256kB of Flash, so you might wish to keep the pointer arrays in RAM, though. If you do this, note that not only are all the elements in it `const float` pointers, but also the `airConditionerCommands` variable itself is `const`. If you omit one of the `const`s, the uVision compiler is keen to keep the array in RAM instead.

(If you have difficulty remembering how to designate variables as `const`, always read them from right to left: the rightmost refers to the variable itself (unless it refers to an array, in which case it refers to the elements); progressing left, separated by `*`, the `const` refers to the pointed to object. So, `const void *a` means `a` can be changed, but the thing it points to cannot be changed; `void *const a` means `a` cannot be changed, but the thing it points to can be changed, and `const void *const a` means neither `a` nor the thing it points to can be changed.)

---

If I were you, I'd also check how many *unique* float variables you have in the arrays overall. If you have less than 256, then `uint8_t` or `unsigned char` would suffice as the command array type; if less than 65536, then `uint16_t` or `usigned short` would work. You then use a float lookup array:

```
const float lookupf[] = {

    0.0f,
#define FLOAT_0 0

    1.0f,
#define FLOAT_1 1

    21.0f,
#define FLOAT_21 2

    /* ... */

    348.0f,
#define FLOAT_348 72

    /* ... */

    3800.0f
#define FLOAT_3800 255
};

const unsigned char AR_KELON_POWER_COOL_21_FANMAX[] = {
    FLOAT_1,    /* 1.0f */
    FLOAT_348,  /* 348.0f */
    /* .. */
    FLOAT_3800, /* 3800.0f */
};
```

with `sendIR` modified from

```
void sendIR(const float *const cmds, ...)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; cmds[i] != 3800.0f; i++) {
        const float cmd = cmds[i];
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

to

```
void sendIR(const float *const cmds, ...)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; cmds[i] != FLOAT_3800; i++) {
        const float cmd = lookupf[cmds[i]];
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

You see, `float` is a 32-bit type, requiring four bytes per value. A `uint8_t`/`unsigned char` is an 8-bit type, requiring just a single type, with the largest possible lookup array (256 entries) taking an additional 1024 bytes of Flash.

Even with `const unsigned short` or `const uint16_t`, which is a 16-bit type, you can often save some memory, since command arrays memory use is halved. (The lookup table still uses four additional bytes per unique float, so the total memory savings may be very small in some cases.)

Since you are already hitting the limit (over 31000 floats), the max. 256-entry lookup array could cut your RAM/Flash use to a quarter (25% of current). But it really depends on how many unique float values you need to store.

I personally do such lookup mapping by putting each command sequence into a separate text file, in a specific subdirectory, with only the numbers, one number per line. Then, I use an `awk` script to gather all the values into one huge lookup file. Then I use another `awk` script to generate the C header file declaring the arrays, including the lookup array; with data array names derived from the file names. It saves a lot of work, and is easy to set up.

Questions?

Comment: Thanks man! You saved the day! Problem solved. The memory usage is now in ROM and it is 4 times less using the lookupf array.

Comment: @user2961765: If you wish to discuss how I'd setup the awk scripts for the C header file generation, you can contact me at the e-mail address shown on my home page. If not, that's fine too :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to declare the array dynamically and free it when no longer necessary, you can take a look at [malloc and free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc) functions.

Comment: That is the problem actually, because I don't know how to use these functions with an array of pointers...

Comment: @user2961765 is there s better time to learn? Necessity is the mother of invention et'al.

Comment: I can't find on the internet (not sure I'm searching right) a good article explaining how to use malloc and free on an array of pointers. Any sugestion?